# Is there a way to find out what printers a user has mapped remotely?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, printing

Remotely as in via command line. Not sure if there's a reg key or something similar I can peek at to see if a user has the correct printers mapped.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you can take a look at the Win32_Printer WMI class,

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_Printer -ComputerName $Comp
```

But, I think this will get you even better results:

```
New-PSSession $Comp | Enter-PSSession
Get-ChildItem Registry::\HKEY_Users\$UserSID\Printers\Connections
Exit
```

Without using PS Remoting, you could do this instead:

```
$Printers = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::Users, $ServerName)
```

You get the idea.  Basically, you need to access that user's registry key with whatever method and enumerate whatever you find in `Printers\Connections`.

Comment: +1, and just for grins, check this link: http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/16643.aspx since they try to get all fancy with voice, etc.

Comment: The `gci Registry::\....` is about to roll up nicely into a powershell function, fyi.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone that's interested in what working code looks like to enumerate the accounts and get a listing of the installed printers, please see below:

```
Get-ChildItem Registry::\HKEY_Users | 
Where-Object { $_.PSChildName -NotMatch ".DEFAULT|S-1-5-18|S-1-5-19|S-1-5-20|_Classes" } | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSChildName | 
ForEach-Object { Get-ChildItem Registry::\HKEY_Users\$_\Printers\Connections -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name }
```

This snippet first enumerates all subkeys under HKEY_Users, it then filters out the default/system account keys and the Classes keys for each user, finally it enumerates each remaining key's `\Printers\Connections` subkeys to output the printer information to the console.

Kudos to Ryan, so thought I would contribute via an answer.